# Tex Live with Flatpak in Linux Mint - management of packages

Tags: pdftex, texlive, linux, chronology

I am using Linux Mint 21.1 Vera.

I believe I am using Tex Live 2023 (installed in Flatpak)

I am actually using TexStudio, and I use pdftex ad default latex engine, set in the preferences of TexStudio.
However I believe that this is in turn using Tex Live 2023 in Flatpak because in the .log file of my last compiled pdf output I read in the first line:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023 - Flatpak) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.8.30)  10 OCT 2023 14:49

I would like to use the latest version of a package (in particular 'chronology').

I have included `\listfiles` in the preamble, and in the .log file I find:

> (/app/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chronology/chronology.sty
> Package: chronology 2015/03/27 v1.1.1 Horizontal timeline

so, apparently I am not using the latest version of this package, which is from August 2023, as per [their page in CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chronology?lang=en).

How can I update the single package, via Flatpak?

If I give the command `flatpak list` in the terminal, I can see only this, which sounds related to LaTeX or TeX:

> TeX Live Sdk extension                          org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.texlive            20210325               22.08                system

which apparenlty is up-to-date. But I am not sure if this is the right package.

I have also tryed to use `tlmgr` but, as far as I understand it points to another installation in my system, which is old 2021 version, because if I give the command `tlmgr update --list` i get the following:

> (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
> (see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
>
> tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2023).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: AFAIK the only why to get updated LaTeX is to manually install upstream TeXLive (see tug.org/texlive). Debian etc changes tlmgr such that it cannot update packages (as they only want people to updage via their own package manager). Sadly Debian and whoever maintains the flatpak does not update their LaTeX package copies very often. Using the upstream TeXLive, you have the full `tlmgr` and can update packages throughout the release cycle for that particular TeXLive (about 10 months).

Comment: Thank you for the info, @daleif !
The question then becomes: 1) how I remove the Flatpak installation that I have now, and 2) how to make sure the frontend TeXStudio points to the right place?

Comment: (1) no idea, (2) make sure you add it to your path in the right space (aka first). It might be a good diea to add it to your `.profile` and `.bashrc` (or what ever). Note that `.profile` is only read at login, so you need to log out and in for it to take effect. Note that `.bashrc` is not enough, as it is never executed when you start a program by say double clicking on a file. (this is one of the most common mistakes for Linux users installing upstream TL)

Comment: Note that you do not need to remove the flatpak version, just make sure the PATH part of the new TL cumes first in the PATH. I personally install in `/opt/texlive/year` as my normal user (not root). Then I make a softlink named `current` in `/opt/texlive` pointing to the current year. As then I don't have to change the path at the next TL release, I can just update the soft link.